# Как вывести имя пользователя parse.com?

Tags: javascript, parse.com

Как с помощью parse.com сделать так, чтобы брало имя человека? Например

```
var name = /* и как тут получить его имя? */;
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу лишь предположить, что вы хотите получить имя текущего залогиненного пользователя.

```
Parse.User.current().getUsername()
```